# showing how many occurrences of that tag exist in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried this to show the number of tags that are in the page, but it said tagName is undefined.
how can I show it and what it's wrong with my code.

```
$('#tag').click(function() {  
    var value = $('#text4').val();
    var mytag = $.parseHTML(value);
    var showIt= $('html').children(mytag[0].tagName).length;
    alert('number of tags are: ' +showIt);
});
```

Comment: there should only be one id per page. Use classes, as multiple id's will cause bugs.

Comment: why do you use both `java` and `javascript` tags?

Comment: @im_benton where do you see multiple ids?

Comment: What kind of input are you expecting in the `#text4` element?

Comment: he's asking about occurrences of "tag". Yet having #tag indicates that he should only have 1.

Comment: @im_benton I think he is referencing to the tag name ;)

Comment: This is confusing because a "tag" — as in `getElementsByTagName()` — is something like `<div>` or `<p>` or `<strong>` ... but you have an **`id`** which is _named_ "tag".  You should also show some html with these IDs in it.

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: What have you put inside $('#text4')? Is it a `<textarea>`, `<input>` or regular HTML element?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon cool chief. I am failing to see where you tried to help answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#text4` is an input box, then you would get this issue if someone types in non-HTML code. For example:

```
$.parseHTML('<div>hi</div>')[0].tagName;
// returns "DIV"

$.parseHTML('hi')[0].tagName;
// returns undefined
```